grep hashed out line from file
I want to exact match the below line in a file

#dtoverlay=piscreen,drm

I have tried
grep "\#dtoverlay=piscreen,drm\" /boot/config.txt

but this also returns a match for

##dtoverlay=piscreen,drm

Also tried with a -w, but it also matches ##dtoverlay=piscreen,drm
grep -w '#dtoverlay=piscreen,drm' /boot/config.txt
##dtoverlay=piscreen,drm


You can use ^ and $ to match beginning and end of line, respectively.

Why did you escape the ending quote? That should have caused an error, since you have no closing quote.

# has no special meaning in regular expressions, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Use:
grep -Fx '#dtoverlay=piscreen,drm'


Don't just post code, explain how it solves the problem.

Use this regex, where ^ and $ match the beginning and the end of the line, respectively:
grep '^#dtoverlay=piscreen,drm$' /boot/config.txt

See grep manual:

Anchoring
The caret ^ and the dollar sign $ are meta-characters that respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of line.

